# Jquery, PHP, Show, Hide, Cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in need of some help working through a piece of jquery. This is my first time kind of diving into this. What I am attempted to do is to show/hide a div based on a checkbox being checked or unchecked. My current code works as expected however after save and refresh although the checkbox might still be checked the div is hidden again because the jquery has been started over. I was wondering if someone could help me rewrite or add to my code how I can keep the jquery active after refresh based on the status of the checkbox. From what I can gather this is going to require something with cookies or local storage but I am completely lost on how to tie it in.

jquery

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#fancy-checkbox-default8').change(function(){
    if(this.checked)
        $('#autoUpdate').show();
    else
        $('#autoUpdate').hide();

});
});
</script>
```

PHP Checkbox

```
echo "<div class=\"form-group3\">";
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ant_ant\" id=\"fancy-checkbox-
default8\" value=\"1\" autocomplete=\"off\"";
if ($ant_ant == "1") { echo " checked=\"checked\" "; }
echo "/>";
echo "<div class=\"btn-group\">";
echo "<label for=\"fancy-checkbox-default8\" class=\"btn btn-default\">";
echo "<span class=\"fa fa-check fa-lg\"></span>";
echo "<span> </span>";
echo "</label>";
echo "<label for=\"fancy-checkbox-default8\" class=\"btn btn-default 
active\">";
echo "Antenna";
echo "</label>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

PHP DIV to Show/Hide

```
echo "<div id=\"autoUpdate\" style=\"display:none\">";
echo "<div class=\"row2\">";
echo "<div class=\"col-xs-12 form-group\">";
echo "<h4 class=\"title\"> <i class=\"fa fa-signal\"></i> Antenna 
Issues</h4>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: There's no PHP in this code. Using `echo` to output HTML does not count. Tag removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already setting the checkbox to checked, but you also need to only hide the div if it's not checked.  In your PHP for the div include the following:

```
echo "<div id=\"autoUpdate\ ";
if ($ant_ant == "1") {echo 'style="display:none"';}
echo ">";
```

Comment: Thank you that helped point me in the right direction. I had to add one more if statement to getting to function correctly back and forth.